# preg_match check if string is surrounded in double or single quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Can someone tell me the regex to see if something is surrounded in double or single quotes.

```
"this is the string"
```

i want it to return false if it quotes are not present at all or not present at the start and the end.

Comment: @rubber: that should be an answer

Comment: A few special cases you might want to consider: Multiline strings (m modifier) empty "" strings (`.*` instead of `.+`), `'malformed quotation"` (taken care of the `\1`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`preg_match('/^(["\']).*\1$/m', $string);`

will return `1` if the string is surrounded by double quotes and `0` if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if (preg_match('#^(\'|").+\1$#', $string) == 1)
```

Comment: you don't really need == 1... I think it will return 0 if its false that will evolute to false either way, but I could be wrong.